# What does "Happiness, then, is its own kind of sacred canon" mean?

Tags: meaning, sentence-meaning

> The important thing to understand is that when we are doing what we
> really love doing, we are making the world around us a happier place
> for everyone. For others as well as for ourselves. When we’re relaxed
> and refreshed, we ourselves become more pleasant for others to be
> around. As a result, our own happiness is a piece of happiness for
> them, as well as for ourselves. ***Happiness, then, is its own kind of
> sacred canon.***

Comment: Please provide some details and research on what words or phrases you find confusing and which ones you have tried to look up in dictionaries.

Comment: @CanadianYankee this "is its own kind of sacred canon"  is not clear for me. What does it mean exactly? what does the writer want to say? I think it's a metaphor.

Answer (score 1):

I think it means that when you're putting happiness out in the world there is almost like a domino effect. You never know what people went through and by putting happiness out there you will bring a little light to everyone you meet.

Comment: How can we say it in a different (clear) way?

Answer (score 1):

In my Christian tradition, canon most frequently means "the selection of sacred texts" ([wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Biblical_canon)). As in, by choosing which books are in and which are out (of the Bible), ancient Christians decided what stories, preaching, and metaphors will echo down the centuries as "sacred text" (canon).

I read this as "When you choose happiness as your primary story, others read happiness when they encounter you." Choosing happiness lets it echo down the centuries as more people are influenced by the happiness you spread.

Comment: it's from this book. look at this please, https://cutt.us/3MiTQ

Comment: Thanks! Given that there didn't seem to be another instance of "canon" in that book (like that was the theme of an earlier chapter), I made my answer more assertive and less "I wonder if..."

Answer (score 0):

A "sacred canon" is a religious law or obligation. This is indeed a metaphor, the writer is saying that being happy helps others, and it is therefore a good thing to be happy, the comparison is to something  that is considered virtuous or a religious obligation.

Comment: How can we say it in a different (clear) way?

Comment: @user70732  There are many expressions with a similar meaning one might use. "Happiness is something of a duty to others",. or "Happiness helps the world in general",  or "Happiness helps everyone around a person". None of these invokes the image of a religious connection, so they don't carry quite the same implication. A Jew might say "Happiness is a *mitzvah*" but the meaning isn't quite the same, and this would obscuree to one who doesn't know that Hebrew word. One might say "sacred duty" instead of "cannon" but this also has a somewhat different implication -- it is rather stronger.

Comment: can we say " Happiness is like a  sacred canon to others"?

Comment: @user70732That would mean that others thought of it as a sacred canon, which is not ther same meaning at all.